# How to deserialize JSON to Dictionary using JSON.NET?

Tags: c#, json

I am querying data from http://www.imdbapi.com and would like to parse the result using [Json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) library. Could someone please tell me how I can use this library to convert the query response into a `Map<string, string>`.

With this code I'm able to get all keys, but how can query the values then?

```
   JObject obj = JObject.Parse(response);
   IList<string> props = obj.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Horrible title, BTW. Could you not think of anything to ask _about_ "JSON Parser"?

Comment: sorry, I'll consider it next time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Just use this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> movieValues = 
     JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(responseFromImdbApi);
```

Just get the values like this:

```
movieValues["title"] 
movieValues["released"]
movieValues["genre"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use an external library when it is already available ?

[JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) works great.

Comment: Here is why. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685429/serializing-data-using-json-net-size-limit/7685498#7685498