# Windows 8 app stuck during JSON.Net deserialization

Tags: json, winrt-xaml

I write Win8 app where I need to deserialize jSon data. If file less than 10 MB - everything is OK, but if not - Win8 app just stuck. No errors or exception - nothing, just stuck. I tested in WPF app - there is no such error and file deserialize correctly, so I think this is WInRT issue.
I am using JSON.Net lib and here is my code for deserializing:

```
var folder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Content");
            var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(@"Models\SpaceShipV2.aemf");
            if (file != null)
            {
                var content = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
                container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EntityDataContainer>(content.ToString());
            }
```

I serialize like this:

```
JsonSerializer json = new JsonSerializer();
        json.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        json.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        string[] name = _fileName.Split('.');
        string fileName = name[0] + ".aemf";
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
        json.Serialize(writer, dataContainer);
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
        fs.Close();
```

Does some already faced with similar issue and know where the problem is?

Comment: post ur json pls also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685429/serializing-data-using-json-net-size-limit

Comment: Post says: 
There is no artificial limit.
Also internally Json.NET reads and writes over streams so there is no memory limit either.
And which json you want me to post? From serialisation?

Comment: if you could show some of it, if it's an array for example paste 1 or 2 items

Comment: I already edited my post to show serialization - I serialize objects (classes), not arrays or structures. I have complex type and I can serialize/deserialize complex type in WPF without problems, but when I serialize in WPF and deserialize in WinRT I have this particular problem. Also I tried to serialize as BSon, but when deserialization I receive error: "Unexpected end when deserializing object. Path ''."